# Laravel - $_ENV not working in service provider

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to build a app that uses a third party API and am using .env.local.php files to store sensitive information. I wasn't having any problems with this method until I added another property to the $_ENV superglobal. I can still access other properties of $_ENV except for the recently added property. However I can access the new property in other parts of my application except in the service provider class I need it in, which throws "syntax error, unexpected '$_ENV'(T_VARIABLE)".

This is more or less my .env.local.php

```
<?php

return array(
    'DB_NAME' => 'placeholder',
    'DB_USER' => 'placeholder',
    'NEW_PROPERTY' => 'test' // Property I can't access in my service provider
);
```

My service provider:

```
<?php

class Service {

    protected $new_property = $_ENV['NEW_PROPERTY'];

}
```

If anyone can provide insight on how I can resolve this situation, I would greatly appreciate the assistance. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Set the variable within the constructor not within a declaration. As these variables cannot be set with a variable value. See answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution would be to set this value within the constructor. Like so;

```
<?php 

class Service {
    protected $new_property;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->new_property = $_ENV['NEW_PROPERTY'];
    }
}
```